# How to add TextBox over PasswordBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dockpanel

I want to put a `TextBox` over the `PasswordBox` to make the encrypted password visible with a button.
When I press the button I want to see the password from the `PasswordBox` in the `TextBox`, but my problem is the alignment, because these two components are in the `Grid`, the `TextBox` is aligned to the right of the `PasswordBox`.

[image: A label spelling "Password", a PasswordBox with four stars, a TextBox spelling "test" and a button spelling "See", all horizontally aligned.]

This is my XAML file:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Waters.NuGenesis.LmsBundle.Plugins.Views.RpcView"

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Waters.NuGenesis.UiEngine.Presentation.Controls;assembly=Waters.NuGenesis.UiEngine.Presentation"
    xmlns:presentation="clr-namespace:Waters.NuGenesis.UiEngine.Presentation;assembly=Waters.NuGenesis.UiEngine.Presentation"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Waters.NuGenesis.LmsBundle.Plugins.ViewModels"
    xmlns:buttons="clr-namespace:Waters.NuGenesis.UiEngine.Presentation.Controls.Buttons;assembly=Waters.NuGenesis.UiEngine.Presentation"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:RpcViewModel}">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DockPanel>

        <controls:PageTitleBlock
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            Title="RPC &amp; SDMS Login"
            Description="Configure SDMS RPC and SDMS Login services." />

        <Grid>

            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 3" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 3 15 0" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type PasswordBox}}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 3" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Content="User Name"
                Visibility="{Binding IsRpcUserNameVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

            <TextBox
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Text="{Binding RpcUserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                Visibility="{Binding IsRpcUserNameVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

            <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Content="Password"
                Visibility="{Binding IsRpcPasswordVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />


            <DockPanel
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2">

                <buttons:SmallButton
                        DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                        Content="See"
                        Margin="15 0 0 0"
                        Command="{Binding ShowPasswordCommand}"  />


                <PasswordBox
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    presentation:UnsafePasswordBox.BindPassword="True"
                    presentation:UnsafePasswordBox.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=RpcPassword, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsRpcPasswordVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

                <TextBox
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Name="TestShowPassword"
                    Text="{Binding DisplayRpcPassword, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Visibility="{Binding SetVisibility}" />

            </DockPanel>

            <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="4"
                Content="Domain"
                Visibility="{Binding IsRpcDomainVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

            <TextBox
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="4"
                Text="{Binding RpcDomain}"
                Visibility="{Binding IsRpcDomainVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

        </Grid>

    </DockPanel>

</UserControl>
```

What I want to modify is this `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="2">

    <buttons:SmallButton
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            Content="See"
            Margin="15 0 0 0"
            Command="{Binding ShowPasswordCommand}"  />


    <PasswordBox
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="2"
        presentation:UnsafePasswordBox.BindPassword="True"
        presentation:UnsafePasswordBox.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=RpcPassword, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Visibility="{Binding IsRpcPasswordVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

    <TextBox
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Name="TestShowPassword"
        Text="{Binding DisplayRpcPassword, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Visibility="{Binding SetVisibility}" />

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: DockPanel does not allow ZIndex based layout (overlay). Replace it with a Grid. You should know that Grid.CGrid.Column has no effect inside a DockPanel. You must use DockPanel.Dock to position child elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the `PasswordBox` and the `TextBox` in a `DockPanel`, but set the attached [`Grid.Row`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.row?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and [`Grid.Column`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.column?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.Grid.Column);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) properties, which **do not have any effect** here, they are only respected by `Grid`.

The [`DockPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) will arrange items next to each other, but not overlapping.

> Defines an area where you can arrange child elements either horizontally or vertically, relative to each other.

You should use a `Grid` instead which the same column for the `PasswordBox` and the `TextBox`.

```
<Grid 
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="2">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <buttons:SmallButton
       Grid.Column="1"
       Content="See"
       Margin="15 0 0 0"
       Command="{Binding ShowPasswordCommand}"/>

   <PasswordBox
      Grid.Column="0"
      presentation:UnsafePasswordBox.BindPassword="True"
      presentation:UnsafePasswordBox.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=RpcPassword, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      Visibility="{Binding IsRpcPasswordVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

   <TextBox
      Grid.Column="0"
      Name="TestShowPassword"
      Text="{Binding DisplayRpcPassword, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      Visibility="{Binding SetVisibility}"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I started already with a grid, see first part, I remove the DockPanel, and you right, is working, but how can I put my button in the right of the fields?

Comment: @Vladut You put this `Grid` **(instead of the `DockPanel`)** inside your other `Grid`. I added the missing `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` from your question in my example, but I corrected it.